# I Commited 3 files, but I see two more additional files after I pushed my changes. Is there any reason why? what to do in this scenario?

Tags: git, github, commit, pull-request, git-revert

I commited three files.  When I did the commit, it showed that I made changes on three files.  However, after I pushed my changes, when I was about to make Pull Request, I saw two more files added that I have not touched or made any kids of changes on.  In Github, I see a total of 5 files now.  Don't where the other two came. I didn't add them for sure.  What kind I do in this scenario?  I only want the 3 files that I made change on to be pushed and do a PR.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately there is no way anyone here can answer your question unless you provide more details. For starters, you could tell us what kind of project this is, the names of the 3 files you added yourself, and the names of the 2 that was added in addition to your three files.

Comment: There are several ways to get rid of the changes to those files in your branch, but before we get to that it would be better to confirm that ignoring those changes is a good thing.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy way will be to delete the files and do a new commit, but why did it happnened?, depending on the software you are using there could be some extra files automatically created like gitignore, those will be created automatically, but as far as I know if they are in the commit it is because they were added, for example, if at some point at the begining you use `git add .` it will put in staging all the new files and naturaly later in the commit, if you dont use later such files they wont show up in the new commits as something with changes and you will only see them in the push, on github you can check the commit history, and a good way to test that will by repeating your steps on the project and commits creation